# Edit Bonita BPM portal

Tags: refresh, portal, business-process-management, bonita

I'm new in Bonita and I've a question to do.

I need to edit the Bonita BPM portal page and refresh it every x minutes.

How can I do it?

Comment: This question is too broad. If you have a specific question about how to implement the functionality, or you require help with a section of your code that has a reproducible bug please rephrase the question to reflect the narrower question.

Comment: I don't know ho to implement this feature in my project i want to refresh the bonita bpm portal page to update the ticket every x minutes. I don't really know where to start. There's a JSP to edit? or what? I'd like an explanation

Comment: what about a cron to ping the portal ?

Comment: sorry, but I did not understand what you said. Can you explain better, maybe adding a few links about this topic. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Bonitasoft's most recent release provides a brand new UI environment based on Angular technology that should be able to meet your needs.

Take a look at this "sneak peek" from this year's BPMNext conference:

http://www.bonitasoft.com/for-you-to-read/blog/bonita-bpm-7-first-peek-ui-designer-bpmnext

Comment: I've the constraints of have to use Bonita community edition 6.3.6 How can I implement on it?

Answer (score 0):

Tasks list available by default in Bonita BPM Portal cannot be easily custom except if you are familiar with GWT. In such situation you might want to dig into [Portal source code](https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-web/tree/6.3.6/portal/src/main/java/org/bonitasoft/console/client/user/task).

As suggest by Greg Harley you can take a look at Bonita BPM 7 (if upgrading become an option). Version 7 bring the "[custom pages](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/pages)" extensions point that allow you to embed new pages in Bonita BPM Portal. Such pages can make use of exact same [REST API](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/product-bos-sp/rest-api) as the default tasks list. You can use Bonita BPM [UI designer](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/product-bos-sp/using-ui-designer) to create your custom page. UI designer allow to create [custom widgets](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/custom-widgets) and so you can create a new widget that can take care of auto-refresh.

Remember that refreshing user tasks list trigger some call to Bonita BPM Engine and so to the database. So make sure that your server is sized appropriately.